# Create Growth Of $1,000 Column in XTS Object in R

Tags: r, xts

I am struggling with what I thought would be a simple task.  I am calculating some investment returns and would like to create a column that shows the growth of $1,000 next to the returns column.  Ideally, this:

```
Index       Return      
4/27/90     -0.011444191    989 
5/30/90     0.000582282     989 
6/28/90     0.007011319     996 
7/30/90     0.005969896     1,002 
10/30/90    0.007221412     1,009
```

The third column is equal the value above times (1+Return) and then fills down.  So the value of 1,009 is obtained by multiplying 1002*(1+0.005969896)

I have tried to do this with the lag function but my head is spinning at the moment from staring at it for too long.

I did succeed in getting the final number of 1,009 using this:

```
 Account = 1000
 for (i in na.omit(sample$Return)){
   Account  = (1+i) * Account
 }
```

However, I would like to have the running total as a column in the xts object.  How can this be done?

This will create the xts object I am using in the table above without the 3rd column.

```
sample <- structure(c(-0.0114441907965878, 0.000582281990849955, 0.00701131947964186, 
0.00596989588048895, 0.00722141248178086), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", src = "yahoo", updated = structure(1414972280.65536, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), index = structure(c(641174400, 644025600, 646531200, 
649296000, 657244800), tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(5L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, "Return"), class = c("xts", "zoo"))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `cumprod`

```
sample$Account <- 1000 * cumprod(1+sample$Return)
sample
                 Return   Account
1990-04-27 -0.011444191  988.5558
1990-05-30  0.000582282  989.1314
1990-06-28  0.007011319  996.0665
1990-07-30  0.005969896 1002.0130
1990-10-30  0.007221412 1009.2489
```